# How to retrieve all sessions "except" specified field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-6, laravel-session

I'm having a hard time searching on how to retrieve all sessions **except** specified field(s). I tried to search [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#retrieving-data) but I can't find the answer. For example, I want to retrieve all below, except the `password`.

```php
session([
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'username' => 'john.doe',
    'password' => bcrypt('sample'),
    //more fields etc. etc.
]);
```

I tried the code below.

```php
session()->except('password')
```

It returns an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::except()

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use a collection.

```
$collection = collect(session()->all());
```

And simply **except** it.

```
$collection->except('password');
```